# Using more than one 'of' in a sentence

Tags: prepositions, repetition

I have trouble with the repetitive usage of 'of' and this is how the sentence goes:

> X and Y make the unbeatable team of strategic essentials of good XYZ.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say it was 'planning and delivery make the unbeatable team of strategic essentials of project management'. Then it does make sense but, stylistically, I prefer: 'planning and delivery, in the strategic essentials of project management, are an unbeatable team' 
Or: 'the unbeatable team for strategic essentials of project management are planning and delivery'
'The strategic essentials of project management have an unbeatable team in planning and delivery'